# Efficiently compute proportions of one data frame from another

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, dplyr

I have this `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- cbind(matrix(rnorm(26,100),26,100),data.frame(id=LETTERS,parent.id=sample(letters[1:5],26,replace = T),stringsAsFactors = F))
```

Each row is 100 measurements from a certain subject (designated by `id`), which is associated with a parent ID (designated by `parent.id`). The relationship between `parent.id` and `id` is one-to-many.

I'm looking for a fast way to get the fraction of each `df$id` (for each of its 100 measurements) out the measurements of its `parent.id`. Meaning that for each `id` in `df$id` I want to divide each of its 100 measurements by the sum of its measurements across all `df$id`'s which correspond to its `df$parent.id`.

What I'm trying is:

```
sum.df <- dplyr::select(df,-id) %>% dplyr::group_by(parent.id) %>% dplyr::summarise_all(sum)

fraction.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(df$id,function(i){
  pid <- dplyr::filter(df,id == i)$parent.id
  (dplyr::filter(df,id == i) %>% dplyr::select(-id,-parent.id))/
    (dplyr::filter(sum.df,parent.id == pid) %>% dplyr::select(-parent.id))
}))
```

But for the real dimensions of my data: `length(df$id)` = 10,000 with 1,024 measurements, this is not fast enough.

Any idea how to improve this, ideally using `dplyr` functions?

Comment: *"I'm looking for a fast way to get the fraction of each `df$id` (for each of it 100 measurements) of out the measurements of it `parent.id`."* I don't understand this sentence. Could you provide an example to elaborate on what you're trying to calculate?

Comment: Edited my post to make this clearer.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your data frame?

Comment: 10,000 by 1,024 - see edited post

Comment: How many unique values for parent.id  are there?

Comment: If you care about speed, converting to long form would probably help. With data.table that looks like `res = melt(DT, id=c("id", "parent.id"))[, v := value/sum(value), by=.(variable, parent.id)][]` and to go back to wide, `dcast(res, id + parent.id ~ variable, value.var = "v")`

Comment: see the microbenchmark data, often base r is the way to go for efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your data is all rows are duplicate of each other, so I changed it slightly to reflect different values in the dataset.

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1L)
df <- cbind(matrix(rnorm(2600), nrow = 26, ncol = 100),data.frame(id=LETTERS,parent.id=sample(letters[1:5],26,replace = T),stringsAsFactors = F))
```

**Code:**

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df)  # assign data.table class by reference

# compute sum for each `parent.id` for each column (100 columns)
sum_df <- df[, .SD, .SDcols = which(colnames(df) != 'id' )][, lapply(.SD, sum ), by = .(parent.id ) ] 

# get column names for sum_df and df which are sorted for consistency
no_pid_id_df  <- gtools::mixedsort( colnames(df)[ ! ( colnames(df) %in% c( 'id', 'parent.id' ) ) ] )
no_pid_sum_df <-  gtools::mixedsort( colnames(sum_df)[ colnames(sum_df) != 'parent.id' ] )

# match the `parent.id` for each `id` and then divide its value by the value of `sum_df`.
df[, .( props = { 
  pid <- parent.id
  unlist( .SD[, .SD, .SDcols = no_pid_id_df ] ) /
    unlist( sum_df[ parent.id == pid, ][, .SD, .SDcols = no_pid_sum_df ] )
  }, parent.id ), by = .(id)]
```

**Output:**

```
#       id       props parent.id
#    1:  A -0.95157186         e
#    2:  A  0.06105359         e
#    3:  A -0.42267771         e
#    4:  A -0.03376174         e
#    5:  A -0.16639600         e
# ---                         
# 2596:  Z  2.34696158         e
# 2597:  Z  0.23762369         e
# 2598:  Z  0.60068440         e
# 2599:  Z  0.14192337         e
# 2600:  Z  0.01292592         e
```

**Benchmark:**

```
library('microbenchmark')
microbenchmark( sathish(), frank(), dan())
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr         min         lq       mean    median         uq       max neval cld
# sathish() 404.450219 413.456675 433.656279 420.46044 429.876085 593.44202   100   c
# frank()     2.035302   2.304547   2.707019   2.47257   2.622025  18.31409   100   a  
# dan()      17.396981  18.230982  19.316653  18.59737  19.700394  27.13146   100   b
```

Comment: This is not particularly fast.

Comment: This is an improvement by a factor 5, over the OPs. Upvoting :)

Comment: I don't know if I think it would be faster. If you want to speed things up, you convert to a matrix where you can, and in that case, rows vs. columns or wide vs long isn't relevant.

Comment: How are you implementing Frank's method?

Comment: nice! feel free to add mine in there if you want for comparison.

Comment: `frank <- function(){ melt(setDT(df), id=c("id", "parent.id"))[, v := value/sum(value), by=.(variable, parent.id)][]}`

Answer (score 2):

Lets compare these options with `microbenchmark`, all using the new definition for the dataset in @Sathish's answer:

OP method:

```
Units: seconds
      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 1.423583 1.48449 1.602001 1.581978 1.670041 2.275105   100
```

@Sathish method speeds it up by a factor of about 5. This is valuable, to be sure

```
Units: milliseconds
      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 299.3581 334.787 388.5283 363.0363 398.6714 951.4654   100
```

One possible base R implementation below, using principles of efficient R code, improves things by a factor of about 65 (24 milliseconds, vs 1,582 milliseconds):

```
Units: milliseconds
     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
21.49046 22.59205 24.97197 23.81264 26.36277 34.72929   100
```

Here's the base R implementation.  As is the case for the OP's implementation, the `parent.id` and `id` columns are not included in the resulting structure (here `fractions`). `fractions` is a matrix with rows ordered according to `sort(interaction(df$id, df$parent.id, drop = TRUE))`.

```
values <- df[1:100]
parents <- split(values, df$parent.id)
sums <- vapply(parents, colSums, numeric(100), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
fractions <- matrix(0, 26, 100)
f_count <- 0
for (p_count in seq_along(parents)){
  parent <- as.matrix(parents[[p_count]])
  dimnames(parent) <- NULL
  n <- nrow(parent)
  for (p_row in seq_len(nrow(parent))){
    fractions[(f_count + p_row),] <- parent[p_row,] / sums[,p_count]
  }
  f_count <- f_count + p_row
}
```

Note: there's still room for improvement. `split()` is not particularly efficient.

Note 2: What "principles of efficient R code" were used?

1. Get rid of names whenever you can
2. It's faster to find things in a matrix than a data frame
3. Don't be afraid of for loops for efficiency, provided you're not growing an object
4. Prefer `vapply` to the other apply family functions.